# waitForXPath a utf-8 string returns time out

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I have some code where I go to a specif page and verify if that page has a string. That string at most of the time is 'GNRE - Web Service' but sometimes i get 'Não há dados' (pt-BR). Because of this the code below return a time out. Does someone know how to check this correctly or if there is something like ut8_encode() to do?
I know the code works because this run correctly when the string is 'GNRE - Web Service'.

Code:

```
await page.waitForXPath("//*[contains(., 'GNRE - Web Service') or contains(., 'Não há dados')]");
```

Error:

```
TimeoutError: waiting for XPath `//*[contains(., 'GNRE - Web Service') or contains(., 'Não há dados')]` failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) or [Promise.any](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/any) which will resolve if either of the text is found.

```
await Promise.race([
  page.waitForXPath("//*[contains(., 'GNRE - Web Service')]"),
  page.waitForXPath("//*[contains(., 'Não há dados')]")
])
```